# Can't change the value of a pointer to equal another pointer

Tags: c++

I have teams as an array of Team objects, and matches is an array of Match objects within the Team objects. `thisMatch` is declared as such:

```
Match* thisMatch = new Match();
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
&(teams[i].matches[foundMatches]) = thisMatch;
// I also tried another method:
(tams[i].matches + foundMatches) = thisMatch;
```

where `foundMatches` is an int.

However, no matter what I do, I keep getting this compiler error:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
                 &teams[i].matches[foundMatches] = thisMatch;
                                                 ^
```

Anyone got any ideas as to what might be going wrong? I can give more information if needed, but I don't think most of it is relevant.

Comment: How 'matches' is declared?

Comment: `teams[i].matches = new Match[num];`

Comment: in that case `matches` is a pointer to an array, not an array of pointers. Which one do you want?

Comment: Applying `&` results in an rvalue; not an lvalue. The error message is about as descriptive as it can get. And `teams[i].matches = new Match[num];` is *not* a declaration; its an assignment. Post *all* the relevant code, declarations included, needed to reproduce the problem, updating the *question* please (not in a comment). The types for `teams`, its members, their types, and the code that is griefing you in a `main()` would be ideal.

Comment: @Conrad.H.Appel.IV `I have teams as an array of Team objects and matches is an array of Match objects`  Arrays are not pointers.  Why are you describing these as "arrays of objects" when they certainly are not?  You still haven't shown how any of these types are `declared`.  The issue others are having is that array `syntax` can be used with pointers, but pointers are not arrays.  We need to see the declaration to know exactly what we're dealing with.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I was, and still am under the impression that an array is essentially a pointer to the first element. And why is it wrong to describe them as an array of pointers?

Comment: @Conrad.H.Appel.IV - Arrays are *not* pointers.  If you describe your type as an "array of objects", then that means that you have a `T someArray[x];`, where `T` is a type, and `x` is a constant value.  There are *no* pointers in that definition.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the block of memory allocated via `new[]` is an array (which doesn't have an identifier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is assign a variable to a constant value. The address of `teams[i].matches[foundMatches]` is predefined already (at the point when you declared the array) and can not be changed.

What are you trying to do is rather change the content of `teams[i].matches[foundMatches]` (in further I assume this is a `Match` object since you said *matches is an array of Match objects within the Team objects*). Changing the content may be done by: `teams[i].matches[foundMatches] = *thisMatch` i.e. assign the content of `thisMath` which is `*thisMath` to an array entry.

Unless you are not using `thisMath` before or after for any manipulations that can not be done to `teams[i].matches[foundMatches]` directly, you can go with `teams[i].matches[foundMatches] = Match()` and instantiate the object, rather then allocating memory and copying it to `teams[i].matches[foundMatches]` forcing afterwords a deallocation as well.

Note: make sure you have a CTOR/CCTOR implemented in the `Match` class as the copy will involve either of one.

Comment: But there is, of course, no need for the `new`. Just do `teams[i].matches[foundMatches] = Match();`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley true, but OP did not specify that there are no change done to `thisMath` on the way.

Comment: Well those changes can be applied directly to `teams[i].matches[foundMatches]`, can they not? Even if not, there is still no reason for `new`. Just create a local object.

Answer (score 0):

```
teams[i].matches[foundMatches] = thisMatch;
```

If `matches` is suppose to contain an array of pointers to matches, it should be declared:

```
Match **matches;
```

You should then allocate it with:

```
team[i].matches = new (Match*)[num];
```

Then the above assignment will work.

Comment: Well when you use the subscript notation, it dereferences the array object and I get this error: `error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Match' and 'Match*')`

Comment: I had to make an assumption about how it was declared. If you want more help, show the declaration of `Team`.

Comment: If `matches` is type `Match*`, then that assignment is trying to assign from a `Match*` to a `Match`. In most normal classes, no, that won't work.

Comment: `matches` wasn't declared within the Team constructor, but was rather dynamically allocated in this method as such: `teams[i].matches = new Match[num];`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley it should work fine because `new Match()` returns a pointer to a `Match` object and it would be assigning to that pointer

Comment: @Conrad.H.Appel.IV: My comment was directed at Barmar's original answer, not at anything you said.